# get every element on odd position in array from for loop to for each loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I am trying to push every element in an array that is on a odd position to an array and the same with elements in even positions. For example:

```
var arr = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g];
//Would give me this
var odd = [a, c, e, g];
var even = [b, d, f];
```

I have a code that works with a for loop and it looks like this:

```
for (var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
    if ((i+2)%2==1) {
    even.push(arr1[i]);
  } else {
    odd.push(arr1[i]);
  }
}
```

but instead of using a for loop I want to use a forEach loop. This is what I did:

```
var arr1 = [1,1,2,2,3,8,4,6];
arr1.forEach(x => {
  if((x) % 2 == 0) {
    even.push(x);
  } else {
    odd.push(x);
  }
});
```

but this doesn't work, instead of outputing this:

```
even = [ 1, 2, 8, 6 ];
odd = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
```

It outputs this, which is wrong:

```
even = [ 2, 2, 8, 4, 6 ];
odd = [ 1, 1, 3 ];
```

So instead of ouputing the element that is in a odd or even position in the array it outputs the elements that are odd or even.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"`if ((i+2)%2==1) { even.push(arr1[i]);`"* There's no point to the `+2` there at all.

Comment: The `.forEach()` gives an index as the second parameter to the callback, so use that instead of `x`... `arr1.forEach((x, i) => {  if(i % 2 == 0) {`

Comment: First you have to decide what you mean by "even" and "odd." In your first code block, you seem to be using "even" and "odd" based on the non-technical perception of position (first position = index 0 = odd) rather than the literal evenness/oddness of the index (first position = index 0 = even). But your `forEach` inverts that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index is passed as the second argument to a [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) callback. You need to replace this:

```
arr1.forEach(x => {
  if((x) % 2 == 0) {
    even.push(x);
  } else {
    odd.push(x);
  }
});
```

by this:

```
arr1.forEach((x, i) => {
  if(i % 2 == 0) {
    even.push(x);
  } else {
    odd.push(x);
  }
});
```

Comment: I'll accept the answer but it won't let me do it right away, I have to wait 9 minutes.